# Parent element has overflow-y; auto and overflow-x: hidden but I need to use absolute positioning on a grandchild element to move it out of div

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make it so that whenever I hover over the div with class `hover-me`, the div with class `popup` will change from being hidden to being shown. This works fine, however, the div with class `popup` is absolutely positioned outisde its parent div with class `element` but because the div with class `elements-container` has `overflow-y: auto` and `overflow-x: hidden`, I can't see it.

I'm wondering if there's any trick I can use to fix this problem without actually removing the `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` from elements-container, because that would break some other stuff.

So I have the following structure right now:

```
<div class="elements-container">
    <div class="element">
        <div class="hover-me">Hover Me</div>
        <div class="popup">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div class="hover-me">Hover Me</div>
        <div class="popup">Hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.elements-container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hover-me {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.hover-me:hover > .popup {
    display: block;
}

.popup {
    position: absolute;
    background: #242528FF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    left: -200px;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Instead of trick you should do it the right way. An absolute position element should be put outside and should not be limited by the size of its container.

Comment: @ThanhTrung But I am positioning it relatively to the left side of the element div, so if it's outside, how would I position it where it's supposed to go?

Comment: Put the div with class popup outside of element container. Also it's not relative to the element container because the container doesn't have a relative position. Right now the popup is relative to the screen